# Is increment integer in cassandra possible in some cases?

Tags: cassandra, counter, consistency

Let's say i have the following table:

```
id text PRIMARY_KEY,
question_asked (int?),
question_answered (int?)
```

This table will updated each time by the same user. He cannot update this table at the same time.

i want to use the following query:

```
UPDATE %s.%s SET question_asked = question_asked + 1 WHERE %s = :execution_id;
```

If i'm using LOCAL_QUORUM when updating for this specific case. Can i have any issues regarding consistency? And if so i will be happy to understand why

I'm familiar with counter and this is how i use it until now. The problem of using counter is that i cannot define TTL.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's impossible in Cassandra until you use special [type called `counter`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCountersConcept.html). But it has it's own problems - because it's not idempotent, then it won't be retried in case of errors on the server side, and this could lead to incorrect results.

As workaround you may try to use [lightweight transactions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html), but they are quite heavyweight, so don't expect high throughput when using them.

Comment: Thanks. As i mentioned - I am familiar with counters but wanted to know if can do a workaround in case i'm not afraid from consistency issues.

Comment: I Looked for other way than counters. I wrote that I cannot use TTL for tables holding counter and in this case it is a problem for me.

Comment: Then you have a choice of either using LWTs, or make optimizations on application level - for example, update specific IDs from the same application, some kind of pipe...

Comment: Thanks. I will give the lightweight transactions a try.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of operations, have a look at counter columns:

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html#counters

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCountersConcept.html

Keep in mind that Cassandra threats counters different from normal data and counter columns need to be in a separate column familiy.-